# Global variable: why "=0" matters?

Tags: c, initialization, global-variables, c11

Scenario:

```
$ cat t0.c t1.c
/* t0.c */
int i = 12;
/* t1.c */
int i INIT;

int main(void)
{
        return 0;
}

$ gcc t0.c t1.c -DINIT="" -std=c11 -pedantic
<nothing>

$ gcc t0.c t1.c -DINIT="=0" -std=c11 -pedantic
ld: /tmp/ccrTTgwH.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `i'; /tmp/cckd6R4u.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why `=0` matters?

UPD:

```
dvl-linux64 $ gcc82 --version
gcc-8.2 (GCC) 8.2.0
```

Try `gcc 11.2.0`:

```
$ gcc t0.c t1.c -DINIT="" -std=c11 -pedantic
ld: /tmp/ccmPBPUT.o:t1.c:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `i'; 
$ gcc t0.c t1.c -DINIT="=0" -std=c11 -pedantic
ld: /tmp/ccxw378s.o:t1.c:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `i';
```

Expected.

Final table:

```
compiler          -DINIT="" leads to multiple definition of `i'?
gcc 8.2.0         NO
gcc 11.2.0        YES
clang 8.0.1       NO
clang 13.0.0      YES
```

Comment: You can only initialize an external variable once. If one file says `i = 12` and the other says `i = 0`, you can't link them together.

Comment: why -D INIT is replace by "=0", "int i;" is very different of "int i = 0;"

Comment: Both commands resulted in multiple definition of `i` when I tried it.

Comment: ... and indeed there **are** multiple definitions in both cases, though historically, some compilers have accepted that situation as an extension, subject to various caveats.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks! With `gcc 11.2.0` I see multiple definition of `i` in both cases. Hm, a  bug in `gcc 8.2.0`?

Comment: An *extension* enabled by default in many traditional Unix compilers, including GCC until pretty recently.  In the latest versions of GCC, you need to enable `-fcommon` to get the old behavior.  (In older GCC, `-fno-common` will turn off that extension.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Nice catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the C standard is concerned, both are invalid as they constitute multiple external definitions for an identifier.  This is actually [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), however most linkers will throw an error in this situation.

In the case of `int i;` in t1.c, this is considered a **tentative definition** because it has no initializer.  This tentative definition however is considered a full definition if there is no other definition in the same translation unit.

This is described in section 6.9.2p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope
> without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with
> the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a *tentative
> definition*. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative
> definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no
> external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly
> as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
> identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation
> unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

However, some compilers such as gcc will take a tentative definition and "join" it with an actual definition in an other object file.  Once you have a full definition (i.e. with an initializer) in multiple object files (even if the initializers are the same), then it generates a multiple definition error.

The `-fcommon` option enables this behavior and `-fno-common` disables it in gcc, although the default depends on the version.

Comment: Re “As far as the C standard is concerned, both should be an error”: There is no “should be.” When there are multiple external definitions of an object, the C standard says the behavior is “undefined,” meaning the standard imposes **no requirements** on the behavior. “Should be an error” would be a requirement. This is a good example of people misunderstanding “undefined behavior” to mean “something you should not do” instead of “a blank space compilers and other tools can fill in with their own definition.” And that is exactly what some tools did; coalescing was a defined behavior.